# Module Structure In Yii Application

Tags: php, yii

My site got three section 
            1. Buyer 
            2. Seller 
            3. Admin. 
To implement these section using *yii* what would be the best structure to develop this site? As i am new in *yii*, should i go with module? Does this module architecture follow *HMVC*? Can you please guide me.
Thanks
Kapur

Comment: Use rights extension, with simple MVC structure, and its done..

Comment: Thank Coder, can you please explain a bit more as i am new in yii. Does module is a good option?

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be using an Role Based Access Control (RBAC).
This is supported well in Yii.

Read more about it here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/328/simple-rbac/

Comment: Thanks veelen, there are few sub modules under admin module like product management, category management etc. So, should i use nested module to achieve it? If so, then how to impose module restriction for nested modules?

Answer (score 0):

Yii is best for create MVC application. you should go this way. by default it has [gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii) 
 which gives you ability to create modules from interface... best way is create 3 module

1. Buyer
2. Seller
3. Admin

good luck :)

Comment: Hi Anri, we have done this approach. But facing problem to implement RBAC on admin sub-modules like product management, category management etc. Here our intention is to provide few access to admin users.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 3 modules separately which can be generated by Gii. It will help you maintain code and a solid structure for you application.

Comment: Hi Namelus, as you advised to create 3 modules separately, then should i go for nested module structure as each of the main module has sub modules like buyer has account. Admin has product, category, RBAC etc.

Comment: @Kapur Yes you can, its totally upto you, how you like to structure your application. The structure will certainly have no affect on application, please keep this in mind. As for RBAC that can be handled with access rules.

Comment: Hi Namelus, i have started to follow the nested modules structure, but facing a problem with CRUD generator. My intention is to have a single model folder for all models. I can manage to create controllers to specific nested module folder but unable to handle the views. View creation has been done to the first level or in root level. As off now i just cut the view folder and paste it to the specific module folder. I don't know you get me or not.